# MSDN Gallery Browse code not working?

Tags: msdn

I had published a sample ([DB Invader](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DB-Invader-A-Database-6fd576f8)) in MSDN Gallery and everything was working fine till 3 days back. I made some changes in code and updated the same on Gallery, but since then when a user clicks on [Browse Code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DB-Invader-A-Database-6fd576f8/view/SourceCode#content), it simply says

> "These files are not yet available for viewing. Please refresh the
>   page in a few minutes and try again."

Just to elaborate the last change I did was to include a ref folder which contains 2 dlls which are required in the application, I do not think this should be an issue as [MongoDB Reference](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MongoDB-Reference-b4136f82/view/SourceCode#content) is also having them.

Any idea what might be going wrong over there. I tried putting .sln file in and out. Including and Excluding bin folders and quite a lot of things. I also asked this question on [MSDN and TechNet Profile and Recognition System Discussions](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/002e5f7b-3779-4075-a88b-051133fd5437/browse-code-not-working-since-yesterday-on-db-invader) but till now no answer.

---

Update (March 25, 01:31 AM IST) : Automatically the problem is resolved. I do not know how the same happened. I do see a post on my Technet question over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved automatically, and got a response on [Technet Profile](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/002e5f7b-3779-4075-a88b-051133fd5437/browse-code-not-working-since-yesterday-on-db-invader)

> the database needed to replicate or refresh, or be indexed or some
>   database thing :)